# Meaning of $$ in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

If `$` represents built-in service in Angular, what does this `$$` prefix mean ? I was just inspecting the scope in Console and saw `$$watchers, $$listeners` etc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$$` prefix variable are treated as private variable, the reason behind adding `$$` before the variable name is, that will avoid the internal variable conflicts and they wouldn't be exposed for external use.

Like in angular you could find many of them, `$$observers`, `$$watchers`, `$$childHead`, `$$childTail`, `$$ChildScope`, etc.